# Weird namespace pollution when importing submodule in a package's __init__.py

Tags: python

main.py:

```
    import package
```

package/__init__.py:

```
    # use function to split local and global namespace
    def do_import():
        print globals().keys()
        print locals().keys()

        import foo as mod

        print locals().keys()
        print globals().keys()

    do_import()
```

package/foo.py:

```
    print 'Hello from foo'
```

Execute main.py will output like this:

```
['__builtins__', '__file__', '__package__', '__path__', '__name__', 'do_import', '__doc__']
[]
Hello from foo
['mod']
['__builtins__', '__file__', '__package__', '__path__', '__name__', 'foo', 'do_import', '__doc__']
```

The `import` in `__init__.py` didn't work as expected.
Notice that the global namespace has a 'foo' which should bind to local 'mod' only

Even a
`exec "import foo as mod" in {'__name__': __name__, '__path__': __path__}`
cannot stop global namespace from being modified

How could this happen?

Comment: @jsbueno I've tried in both python 2.7.3 and 3.2.3 (with proper print statements), and it appears in both versions for me.

Comment: I understood what is happening -- I am trying to put it in words right now.

Comment: @jsbueno, am I wrong in my answer?  I'm not 100% sure, as this is not the behaviour I expected, though I've never really looked at globals before/after imports before.

Comment: @AdamWagner: indeed, your answer is not correct. I am about to post mine

Comment: @jsbueno removing my answer for now... I cannot reproduce it with a simpler test case.. I believe I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! Tricky, but I got it!

"foo" is not a simple "other package" - it is seem by Python as a sub-module of your "package" module.

When you first run "package" - either importing it from an external script, or by running it with the `-m` command line switch (but not if you run `python package/__init__.py` directly from the command line), the "package" module is parsed, and added to the `sys.modules` dicticionary (on the `sys` module).

When the sub-module `foo` is read, besides being placed directly under `sys.modules` under the key `["package.foo"]`, it is also set as an attribute to its parent module. Therefore it would be avaliable in your Python app as `package.foo`. What happens is that setting an attribute in `sys.modules["package"]`, has the same effect than setting a key in `package/__init__.py` globals in runtime. That is what is happening.

I hope I could translate the process into words properly - if not, just ask again by commenting.

--
Since this is probably happening in real code you have, and the equivalent of "do_import" is being called from code outside your package (and have the side effects of making your sub-modules appear on the package's global namespace), there is no easy work around on the way you are doing it. My suggestion is to just add an underscore (`_`)  at the beggining of the sub-modules names if they are not intended to be called from general code from outside your package. (It also won't show up if someone does `from package import *` in this case)

Comment: That makes sense!  I was thinking it had something to do with the package being a, well, package.. but I couldn't pinpoint exactly what was going on... good work!

Comment: I have another quesiton about __init__.py in a package. When I want to import a submodule using __import__(eg. enumerating submodules under the package directory), I have to use `__import__( __name__ + '.foo' )` or `__import__( 'foo', globals() )`. What happened here?

Comment: Likely (haven  checked) - Python's import mechanism checks for the `__file__` global variable when determining the dir to prepend to the search path. Ths can be made explicit by passing the second argument to `__import__`. When using the first form, the directory where "foo" is is not in the search path of the `__main__` program which is in effect by default - but `package` is.